# How to inject a mixin from inside a component?

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to inject a mixin from inside a component in ember ?

```
import mixinCreator from 'ember-mixin-....'; 

    export default Ember.Component.extend({

      didReceiveAttrs() {

        var aMixin = mixinCreator(...);

        this.reopen(aMixin );

     }

  });
```

Comment: Refer this http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extend component with your mixin...

```
export default Ember.Component.extend(mixinCreator, { ...
```